# How can i place "Comment:" on red line?

Tags: html

[image]

How can I place "Comment:" on red line as shown in the above picture? I know it's a little bit of a silly question, but as a beginner it would be helpful for me.
Here is a code snippet:

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  padding: 5px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>FeedBack Form</h2>
<strong>Name:</strong> 
<input type="text" />
<br>
<br>
<strong>Comment:</strong> 
<input type="text" style="height:100px; width:250px;" />
<br>
<br>
<strong>Email Address:</strong> 
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: comment on red line? could you please explain it a bit more clearly..

Comment: are you trying to add more text above that input field or put text inside that field? Or do you mean you want to move the text 'Comment:' to visually be where that red line is

Comment: Do you want the 'Comment' text to align with the text box?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/bw86fs3m/)

Please add **`vertical-align: text-top;`** or **`vertical-align: top;`** as style for the `input`.

Add the below given to your CSS

```
input[type="text"]{
        vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
<strong>Comment:</strong> <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:250px; vertical-align:top;"/><br><br>
```

I just added `vertical-align: top` to you input text.

But as a suggestion, I think you may want to use textarea instead input text. And inline css styles is not a thing I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align` css property

```
<strong style="vertical-align: top;">Comment:</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FeedBack Form</title>
    <style>
        body {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height:550px;
            width:550px;
            padding:5px;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style
</head>
<body>
<h2>FeedBack Form</h2>
<strong>Name:</strong> <input type="text" /><br><br>
<strong style="vertical-align: top;">Comment:</strong> <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:250px;"/><br><br>
<strong>Email Address:</strong> <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```